# Using stem to control Tor in python33

Tags: python-3.x, tor

I am trying to use [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/index.html) to have a small script run through Tor. I can't seem to get stem to work. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from stem.connection import connect_port
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

controller = connect_port(port=9151)

def change():

    controller.authenticate()
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

def getIp():
    print (urllib.request.urlopen("http://my-ip.heroku.com").read(30).decode('utf-8'))

def connectTor():
    controller = connect_port(port=9151)
    controller.connect()
    getIp()
    if not controller:
        sys.exit(1)  
        print("nope")

def disconnect():
    controller.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connectTor()
    getIP()
    change()
    getIp()
    disconnect()
```

Basically, all of the IPs that display are the same, when in theory, they should all be different. What can I do to make this code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Tor you need to direct traffic through its SocksPort (Tor acts as a local socks proxy). In your code above you don't have anything attempting to make urllib go through Tor.

For examples see Stem's [client usage tutorials](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html). I'm not sure offhand if SocksiPy or PycURL have Python 3.x counterparts. If not then you'll need to find an alternative.

Comment: thanks for answering! socks doesnt have a 3.x counterpart but pycurl does. is it possible to do this without socks?

Comment: ok, so when i use the pycurl example without the socks (which im assuming will work), i get "OSError: 'tor' isn't available on your system. Maybe it's not in your PATH?",  should tor be somewhere specific? providing torrc_path doesnt seem to do anything